# confirm executed multiple times, console.log only once in on('click') event

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, confirm, bpopup

I tried making a jquery function that works together with a bpopup (iframe) function. I want to show a confirmation message before trying to close the iframe. I added a confirm message that shows after a change but after i submit the form the confirm box gets duplicated. I tried debugging and checked how many times the function got executed so i did a console.log but this console.log only executed once when the confirm message got executed multiple times. this is the function:

```
function confirm_changed(){
    var changed = false;
    $('.b-modal', parent.document).on('click', function(){
        if(changed && confirm('Weet je zeker dat je dit scherm wilt verlaten?')){
            $('.b-modal', parent.document).removeClass('changed');
        }
    });
    $(document).one('input', function(){
        $('.b-modal', parent.document).addClass('changed');
        changed = true;
    });
}
```

This function gets called in the document.ready and this is the bpopup prototype function where i added the condition for the confirm message:

```
function r(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(c('.changed').length === 0){
            a.modal && c(".b-modal." + b.data("id")).fadeTo(a.speed, 0, function(){
                c(this).remove()
            });
            a.scrollBar || c("html").css("overflow", "auto");
            c(".b-modal." + e).unbind("click");
            f.unbind("keydown." + e);
            k.unbind("." + e).data("bPopup", 0 < k.data("bPopup") - 1 ? k.data("bPopup") - 1 : null);
            b.undelegate(".bClose, ." + a.closeClass, "click." + e, r).data("bPopup", null);
            clearTimeout(H);
            G();
            return !1
        }
    }, 0);
}
```

This function closes the iframe.

I added the timeout so that this function gets executed after the confirm message. after the form gets submitted and everything went through the validations the class gets deleted.

Comment: you may try with `off()` like `$('.b-modal', parent.document).off().on('click', function(){`

Comment: That didn't fix the problem, this function also seems to give problems with the input fields. Sometimes i can't focus the fields and after a while of waiting i can use them again. There doesn't seem to be any logic moment when this happens.

Comment: The console gives an error message: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null'. I get the feeling that somehow the parent.document gets duplicated but i'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I figured it out, i put a function in the prototype that checks for the confirmation instead of in a different js script.